# How to style only the pager-indexes of a GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, web, webforms

I use `GridViews` on several pages with pager-indexes in style "Next/Previous/Last/First". I need to apply special styles to them - color, font-size. The problem is if I use `tr:last-of-type` and the entries are less than one page, the styles go to the last row, I have anchors in the `GridView`.

Is there a way to select only the indexes if such exist?

Comment: Can you show the gridview code ?

Answer (score 0):

You did mention the `gridview` and didn't provide any code so I am assuming you are using the `gridview` default pager if that's the case then there is property to `gridview` to set the page index style that is

```
   PagerStyle-CssClass="yourcssstyleclassname"
```

Comment: Thanks. This  will solve the issue. In meantime I found a workaround - The pager is in a separate inner table so table table selector works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CssClass for the PagerStyle

```
<PagerStyle Wrap="False" CssClass="GridPager" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
```

The following is the css for the GridView pager:

```
tr.GridPager td {
    height: 26px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.GridPager a, .GridPager span {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size:80%;
}

.GridPager a {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #969696;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    height: 20px;
    font-size:80%;
}

.GridPager span {
    background-color: #ccdef4;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #969696;
    height: 20px;
}
```